Identify stone countertop and fix bleach stain
After doing a bunch of reading, I am now stuck as I don't want to make a bad problem worse. I have a bleach stain (Domestos) on a bathroom stone countertop. From what I understand I need to make a poultice and then try to seal it again, but first (it seems?) I need to know the countertop material. If you have some advice on the poultice and sealant that would be an added bonus!
I've put a photo of the topside (with stain) and bottomside of the counter below.


Thanks in advance.
